# How are we supposed to get the "Peer pressure" badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

The peer pressure badge is awarded if you get 3 downvotes on a question and you delete it. How are you supposed to get it, considering that you have a Reputation loss, just because of badge?

Comment: Deleting the question will revert the reputation lost, so you'll end up with the badge and no change in reputation. The only real negative is that you've probably come a step closer to activating the question ban. That and you have badge that most people wouldn't be proud of.

Comment: You could try a Minecraft mod error log, or anything non-Fallout 4

Comment: Don't get the 3 downvotes. Ironically I could delete this and gain the badge ...

Comment: Down votes might be because it is kinda self explanatory. Just a guess, though.

Comment: @deprilula28 - I think deleting this post will only get you the badge in the meta.  Maybe someone else can clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get it just like it says, for deleting a post that has 3+ downvotes. It's one of those things most people don't actively seek, because it means you've intentionally made a bad post that the community doesn't like for whatever reason. So yes, it means you've lost at least 6 rep (2 for each downvote), but you have a badge. It's sort of a consolation prize, as it were (although you can only get it once, I believe.)

Comment: Yes, you're not supposed to seek it out, it's designed to encourage the good behavior of deleting posts the community deems to be bad

Comment: Also note that 1 question upvote is worth +5 rep (and answers are +10), meaning that the -6 rep suffered from having a question getting downvoted 3 times is minimal.

Comment: "..a post that **as** 3+ downvotes..." Just poiting that... @Robotnik That's true. Kinda impressed my first answer was a moderator's.

Comment: @deprilula28 - Unionhawk's comment says it all really.  If the post is deemed bad by the community, its down to you to remove it.  Your reward is a badge.  I believe the badge is aimed at cleaning up bad posts rather than getting users to intentionally make posts just to pick up the badge.